# WPF pass parameter to page with factory delegate

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection

I dont how to pass parameter to new page, I have factory delegate that help me with dependecy injection but I also want to pass parameter throught Navigate service.

App.xml

```
private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<Home>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<Home>>(ServiceProvider => ServiceProvider.GetService<Home>);

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<PrinterDetails>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<PrinterDetails>>(ServiceProvider => ServiceProvider.GetService<PrinterDetails>);

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ProvinceList>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<ProvinceList>>(ServiceProvider => ServiceProvider.GetService<ProvinceList>);

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IProvinceListViewModel, ProvinceListViewModel>();
        
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
    }
```

I navigate from page PrinterDetails to page ProvinceList using NavigationService(when i click btnProvince_Click())

```
public partial class PrinterDetails : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Func<ProvinceList> ProvinceListFactory { get; }

    
    public PrinterDetails(Func<ProvinceList> provinceListFactory)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        PrinterService printerService = new PrinterService();
        cmbPrinterList.ItemsSource = printerService.PrinterList();
        ProvinceListFactory = provinceListFactory;
   
    }


    private void btnProvince_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
  
        ProvinceList nextPage = this.ProvinceListFactory.Invoke();
        NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
    }
}
```

ProvinceList page that i want to pass parameter

```
public partial class ProvinceList : Page
{
    private readonly IProvinceListViewModel _provinceListViewModel;

    public ProvinceList(IProvinceListViewModel provinceListViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _provinceListViewModel = provinceListViewModel;
        GetProvinceList();
    }

    private void GetProvinceList()
    {
        //How to get parameter from previous page
    }
}
```

Comment: You can implement a public property on ProvinceList. Then PrinterDetails can set this property after it has created the instance using there factory. Alternatively, you can add this parameter to the constructor of ProvinceList and then configure the IoC container to inject the parameter.  If the parameter is a dynamic result you must configure your factory to accept this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a public property on `ProvinceList`. Then `PrinterDetails` can set this property after it has created the instance using the factory:

```cs
private void btnProvince_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  double parameter = 4.5;
  ProvinceList nextPage = this.ProvinceListFactory.Invoke();
  nextPage.Value = parameter;
  NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add this parameter to the constructor of `ProvinceList` and then configure the IoC container to inject the parameter. If the parameter is a dynamic result you must configure your factory to accept this parameter.
Register the factory delegate that accepts a parameter e.g. `Func<IProvinceListViewModel, double, ProvinceList>`, which is used to construct the type:

```cs
// This example assumes that the constructor of ProvinceList 
// requests two parameters of type IProvinceListViewModel and double
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<double, ProvinceList>>(serviceProvider => doubleParameter => 
{
  IProvinceListViewModel viewModel = serviceProvider.GetService<IProvinceListViewModel>();
  return new ProvinceList(viewModel, doubleParameter);
});

serviceCollection.AddTransient<IProvinceListViewModel, ProvinceListViewModel>();
```

And use the factory as follows:

```cs
public PrinterDetails(Func<double, ProvinceList> provinceListFactory)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ProvinceListFactory = provinceListFactory;
}

private void btnProvince_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  double constructorParameter = 4.5;
  ProvinceList nextPage = this.ProvinceListFactory.Invoke(constructorParameter);
  NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
}
```

---

Answer to follow up question:

```cs
// This example assumes that the constructor of ProvinceList 
// requests two parameters of type IProvinceListViewModel and double
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<double, ProvinceList>>(serviceProvider => doubleParameter => 
{
  IProvinceListViewModel viewModel = serviceProvider.GetService<IProvinceListViewModel>();
  Func<POPList> popListFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<Func<POPList>>();
  return new ProvinceList(viewModel, doubleParameter, popListFactory);
});

serviceCollection.AddTransient<IProvinceListViewModel, ProvinceListViewModel>();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<POPList>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<POPList>>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<POPList>);
```

```cs
private void btnProvince_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  double constructorParameter = 4.5;
  ProvinceList nextPage = this.ProvinceListFactory.Invoke(constructorParameter);
  NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
}
```

Comment: I tried add parameter to constructor but now i have error (where I bolded) `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<double, ProvinceList>>(serviceProvider => **parameter** => new ProvinceList(parameter));`
**Unable to convert block "lambda expression" to the intended delegate type because some return types in the block do not implicitly convert to the delegate return type**
Problem is because my class have now two params 
```public ProvinceList(IProvinceListViewModel provinceListViewModel, double param)```

Comment: I changed  `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<ProvinceList>>(ServiceProvider => ServiceProvider.GetService<ProvinceList>);`  to  `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Func<double, ProvinceList>>(serviceProvider => parameter => new ProvinceList(parameter));`  because i wanted to pass argument so i changed my class from   `public ProvinceList(IProvinceListViewModel provinceListViewModel)
{
...
}`  to  `public ProvinceList(IProvinceListViewModel provinceListViewModel, double param)
{
 ...
}`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your `ProvinceList` constructor now requests two parameters: one `IProvinceListViewModel` and a `double`? I have updated my answer to give you an example how to create the Func. We use the ServiceProvider to get an instance of IProvinceListViewModel. The double parameter is externally passed to the delegate. (I hope you understand that my example chose `double` because you didn't show the actual type. To highlight the pattern I made up the parameter of type of `double` - only for the example. Maybe I piked the correct type by accident?).

Comment: At the beginning i wanted to inject service to my **ProvinceList** constructor so that's why I pass **IProvinceListViewModel** to constructor. But now I want to inject service and pass parameter from previous page (PrinterDetails). The parameter type doesn't matter I just wanted to test it with double. I copied your code but now I say that semicolon is missing after **(viewModel, parameter)**. When I put it it gives me **The "Func <IProvinceListViewModel, double, ProvinceList>" delegate takes no arguments 1**

Comment: My bad. I have fixed the registration part. This should be it. I was kind of sloppy here.

Comment: It's basically like: if the parameter is a registered type we use the `ServiceProvider.GetService` to create an instance. For all other parameters we must add them as generic type parameter to the `Func` factory delegate as those parameters are directly passed to the delegate on invocation.

Comment: It works, now i wanted to repeat that to next page so I added third parameter  ```public ProvinceList(IProvinceListViewModel provinceListViewModel, double param, Func<POPList> pOPListFactory)
{
...
}```  and I am going to repeat navigation to new page  ```POPList nextPage = this.POPListFactory.Invoke();
            //NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);```
After adding third parameter ofcourse i need to change that **serviceCollection**. How to add that third parametr and is this good practice?

Comment: I have updated the example to add your case. I hope you get the idea now.

Comment: Yes, now I get it, Thank you very much for help. God bless you.